# How can i fix peer sending data with error? (Multipeer Connectivity framework)

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

so I have an Xcode project where I use the Multipeer Connectivity framework. I tried this with an iphone 6 on IOS 12.4.2 and an iphone 6 simulator on IOS 12.4.4. They detect each other, but when it comes to connecting, it appears that the peer trying to connect sends wrong data thus it disconnects after the timeout time. Console message is this one :

```
2020-01-19 18:41:58.038549+0100 MultipeerConnectivityTest[25092:716509] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
2020-01-19 18:42:02.577076+0100 MultipeerConnectivityTest[25092:716509] [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser] PeerConnection connectedHandler (advertiser side) - error [Unable to connect].
2020-01-19 18:42:02.577256+0100 MultipeerConnectivityTest[25092:716509] [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser] PeerConnection connectedHandler remoteServiceName is nil.
Nous avons recu une invitation de <MCPeerID: 0x600003f7c290 DisplayName = (.:/|\:.) 5G> 
2020-01-19 18:42:13.150877+0100 MultipeerConnectivityTest[25092:716834] [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser] Data from peer [(.:/|\:.) 5G,22BCEE4D] received with error Connection closed.
```

The error says something about "remoteServiceName" but none of my variables have a property like that.

This is my code :

```
import MultipeerConnectivity
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    //MARK: - Property
    var peerID : MCPeerID!
    var session : MCSession!
    var advertiser : MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
    var browsingService : MCNearbyServiceBrowser!

    //MARK: - Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
        session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .none)
        session.delegate = self
        advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "test")
        advertiser.delegate = self
        browsingService = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peerID, serviceType: "test")
        browsingService.delegate = self

        advertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()



    }

    @IBAction func startAdvertising(_ sender: Any) {
        browsingService.startBrowsingForPeers()
        //print(browsingService)
    }
    @IBAction func stopAdvertising(_ sender: Any) {
        browsingService.stopBrowsingForPeers()
        //print(browsingService)
    }
}
//MARK: - Delegate Extensions
extension ViewController : MCSessionDelegate{

    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        switch state {
        case .connected:
            print("La peer \(peerID) vient de se connecter")
        case .connecting:
            print("La peer \(peerID) se connecte")
        case .notConnected:
            print("La peer \(peerID) vient de se deconnecter")
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        var message : String
        do {
            message = try JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: data).message
            print("Message recu de \(peerID) : \(message)")

        }catch {
            print("Impossibilité de décoder la data envoyée par \(peerID)")
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) { //Pas de stream dans notre programme

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
        print("Donné en corus de réception de \(peerID) : \(progress)")
    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {

    }


}

extension ViewController : MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {
    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
        print("Nous avons identifié la peer \(peerID)")
        //print("Invitation")
        browsingService.invitePeer(peerID, to: session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        print("La peer \(peerID) vient de disparaitre de nos radars")
    }
}

extension ViewController: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {
    func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data?, invitationHandler: @escaping (Bool, MCSession?) -> Void) {
        if advertiser.serviceType == "titouan-test"{
            print("Nous avons recu une invitation de \(peerID)")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm french, this is why print arent english but they are not very important if you are good with Multipeer Connectivity.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nope... still waiting for an answer

Comment: In iOS 14 I'm facing same issue when testing with Simulator and Real Device.

Comment: Did you resolve this issues?  I'm seeing the same thing with two iPhones, one on iOS 16 and other iOS 17.